# Where is POSIX Ex editor on Mac?

Tags: macos, filesystem, vi, binary

Since [Ex is a standard Unix editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(text_editor)) (standardized by POSIX), I expect to be shipped with OS X, however it's linked into `vim` instead as shown below:

```
$ stat /usr/bin/ex
  File: ‘/usr/bin/ex’ -> ‘vim’
```

My goal is to test some syntax within Ex it-self (not using extended `vim`-like `ex` syntax) in order to check if my command is [POSIX-compliant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html).

Therefore where I can find the original Ex editor on OS X? Or if it was removed or not shipped with, how can I get it back?

Comment: I believe vim has a mode which it claims to be a standard-compliant implementation of `ex`. Note that for any other package you install, you only have the author's word that it is standards compliant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could install it using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).
It is part of the brew `ex-vi` package, e.g.:

```
brew install ex-vi
```